# Buffer output is different for same attribute value in different layers (QGIS 3)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, buffer

I have two line layers with almost the same attribute table. And I want to create a buffer with "variable distance buffer" from the line's attribute "raiometade" and "raio_metade".

Layer 1 is getting the right result (a buffer with distance of 2572 meters), but the layer 2 output is incorrect and I don't know why (it is generating an output buffer with distance of 100 meters).

Both lines are located in the same location and the only real difference is that Layer 1 was generated directly using the tool box (variable distance buffer) and layer 2 was generated using the following code on the python console:

```
 processing.run("saga:variabledistancebuffer", {'SHAPES':line,'DIST_FIELD':'raio_metade','DIST_SCALE':1,'NZONES':1,'DARC':5,'DISSOLVE       ':True,'POLY_INNER       ':False,'BUFFER':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

Table of layer 1:

[image]

Table of layer 2:

[image]

Buffer resulted from layer 1:

[image]

Buffer resulted from layer 2:

[image]

Comment: Do both layers have the same CRS?

Comment: Yes, they do have the same CRS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a virtual layer.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Feel free to add any field of interest from the layer.

```sql
select st_buffer(geometry,raio_metade) as geometry, raio_metade  
from line
```